# Clip command not working for copying output

Tags: batch-file, google-chrome-extension, command-prompt, clip, chrome-native-messaging

I have created a batch file which i am invoking through Chrome Native messaging.It runs fine with the correct response but the clip command is not working for me.I do not want the output to be redirected to a file.If i directly go to system path and run form there "C:\Windows\System32>TRACERT.EXE www.google.com | clip", this works fine.Also i do not want to remove the "call" command as removing it is causing the command prompt to close.Is there a way to achieve that ? 
[image: Output]
Thanks

Jaideep

```html
Batch File 

@echo off
set Pathname="C:\Windows\System32"
cd /d %Pathname%
start call TRACERT.exe www.google.com | clip
PAUSE

JS -

document.getElementById('but1').addEventListener(
      'click', connect);

function connect() {
 
  var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo"; 
  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
}
}

Manifest -- 

{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "My Application",
  "path": "C:\\Extension\\trace.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: All you need do is `TRACERT.exe www.google.com | clip`. See my answer here for an explanation of how to start programs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371443/what-do-all-commands-in-batch-mean-and-do

Comment: Thanks Noodles for your reply. The change suggested by you works and copies the output also, but i want to have the response on the screen in the command prompt which is not coming after doing the changes.